# android custom tab layout selected tab background

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-selector

I'm setting up a little application, which requires a tab layout. I've implemented everything with fragments and everything is working very well, the only thing I really cant figure out is the background of the selected tab: here is what I did:

I've started from "tab and pager" ActionBarSherlock's samples. I had put the tabs in an Horizontal scrollview, and created in the drawable folder the following selector  called tab_bg_selector :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  Active tab -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
    <!--  Inactive tab -->
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_deselected" />
    <!--  Pressed tab -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <!--  Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

and the tabs are being added in this way

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(getTabSpec(STEPS.STEP1_MATERIAL, "firstTab"), FirstTab.class, null);
```

where mTabsAdapter is a class extending FragmentPagerAdapter (created by the example's developer, below to all there is the code for the sake of completeness) and getTabSpec is

```
public TabSpec getTabSpec(String tag, String title) {
        View tabview;
        TabSpec ts;

        tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), title);

        ts = this.mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                return new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
        return ts;
    }
```

and createTabView is

```
private View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        tv.setText(text);
        return view;
    }
```

R.layout.tabs_bg is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabsLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
    android:padding="10dip" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tabsText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="15dip" android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

tab_text_selector is this

this is the class of which mTabAdapter is an instance

```
/**
     * This is a helper class that implements the management of tabs and all
     * details of connecting a ViewPager with associated TabHost. It relies on a
     * trick. Normally a tab host has a simple API for supplying a View or
     * Intent that each tab will show. This is not sufficient for switching
     * between pages. So instead we make the content part of the tab host
     * 0dp high (it is not shown) and the TabsAdapter supplies its own dummy
     * view to show as the tab content. It listens to changes in tabs, and takes
     * care of switch to the correct paged in the ViewPager whenever the selected
     * tab changes.
     */
    public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final TabHost mTabHost;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
        private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

        final class TabInfo {
            public final String tag;
            public final Class<?> clss;
            public final Bundle args;
            public Fragment fragment;

            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        class TabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
            private final Context mContext;

            public TabFactory(Context context) {
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mViewPager = pager;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            tabSpec.setContent(new TabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

            info.fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

            try {
                TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) mTabs.get(position);// this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
                if (mLastTab != newTab) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    if (mLastTab != null) {

                        if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                            ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                        }
                    }
                    if (newTab != null) {
                        if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                            newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(TabFragment.this, newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                            ft.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                        } else {
                            ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                        }

                    }

                    mLastTab = newTab;
                    ft.commit();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogHelper.WriteLogError("error in onTabChanged function", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
            // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
            // The jerk.
            // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
            // ViewPager.
            // TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            // int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            // widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
//          mTabHost.getTabWidget().focusCurrentTab(position);
            // widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    }
```

Ok, after all this code here is the problem:

the selector for the non selected tabs works fine (except for the textColor which is white instead of being black), but when I select a tab the tab becomes completly black, I i click again on the tab everything is displayed correctly. here is an image to explain better the problem

[image]

I really can't figure out what's the problem, I hope someone can helo me

thanks

EDIT: I found the problem: during the initialization of tab layout, i had put all tabs to be focusable in touch mode, because when by code I need to show a tab that is not visible (the tabs can be a lot) using

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().focusCurrentTab(position)
```

which do not work if I do not set tabs to be focusable in touch mode.

I can solve this?

thanks

Comment: `android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"` Is this just a mistake in pasting here?

Comment: no sorry, i added it to the code